# Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app' - run-android after creating project

Tags: android, react-native

After creating a react native project, I tried to run it on my android device. I enter `adb devices` into the terminal, I saw my device. I ran `react-native run-android`. And after a while `Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'` popped up.

```
Jetifier found 962 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers
...info Starting JS server...
'D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. 
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8
081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
```

Here is react-native info

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Windows 7 6.1.7601
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz
    Memory: 881.91 MB / 3.97 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.17.3 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.2.0.0 AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246
  Languages:
    Python: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
    react-native: 0.62.0 => 0.62.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I ran `gradlew tasks` and I did not see `installDebug` under the install tasks. I am sure that I set up the environment variables correctly, including android SDK, JDK. I tried reinstalling react-native. I put the location of my sdk in local.properties under android folder. I ran `gradlew installDebug` and `installDebug not found in root project '[app's name]'` appeared. None of the solutions on the internet worked.

Can anyone please help me to sort out this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also faced the same problem.
Here is what works for me.

I opened the Android Project in Android Studio.
This can be located at YourReactNativeProjectFolder/android

When I opened this project in Android Studio, it was missing the configuration. Wait for some time and allow Android Studio to configure it and ask you to update the Gradle. Update the Gradle and now you can run your project from the Android Studio or using the command line "`npx react-native run-android`"

I hope that it will be helpful.

Best

Answer (score 5):

The solution is loading the /android folder in the Android Studio and let it update the Gradle. After that you will be able to run `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 3):

Here is what forked for me on a Mac m1:

1. `npx react-native run-android` raises metro terminal (stay open metro).
2. Open project in Android in the folder `android` and launch Emulator on Device.
3. Later android launch the app and Device error.
4. Run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` (in the `android` folder).
5. In Device press reload.

Answer (score 2):

try the following command at the project root:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug
```

Comment: assembleDebug didn't work `Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'Prism'.`

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Run metro,

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

then run the below command,

```
cd android

adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 //in the android folder
```

then,

```
cd ..

npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the  same error.Try the following command, it will show the exact error of the code.

cd android && ./gradlew buildRelease

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and this is what I did to solve it.

1. I deleted the **android** and **iOS** folders in my react native project.
2. I run **npx react-native eject** (Incase you don't have eject, install it by running yarn add eject.
3. I run **npx react-native run-android** again