# Trying to run react-native on real device but error occurred with installDebug

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, react-native

I am trying ro run react native on my android phone but this error occured . I have used react-native-cli.And i have not yet changed the code of the react-native provide.Please help . Thanks in advance

error is here =>

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Buntu\Documents\projects\Contactapp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Buntu\Documents\projects\Contactapp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Buntu\Documents\projects\Contactapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Buntu\Documents\projects\Contactapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

C:\Users\Buntu\Documents\projects\Contactapp>

Comment: Which version of gradle you're using right now? You can find it from `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` here. Try to replace your `distributionUrl` with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip` and enter into `android` directory and run `./gradlew clean`. Let me know whether it's working not.

Comment: I had same issue I was able to solve it [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61003977/11309492)